# Unit test Angular 2 service subject

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, rxjs, subject

I'm trying to write a test for an angular service which has a Subject property and a method to call `.next()` on that subject.

The service is the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class SubjectService {
  serviceSubjectProperty$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  callNextOnSubject(data: any) {
    this.serviceSubjectProperty$.next(data);
  }
}
```

And the test file for that service:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { SubjectService } from './subject.service';

describe('SubjectService', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        SubjectService
      ]
    });
  });

  it('callNextOnSubject() should emit data to serviceSubjectProperty$ Subject',
    inject([SubjectService], (subjectService) => {
      subjectService.callNextOnSubject('test');

      subjectServiceProperty$.subscribe((message) => {
        expect(message).toBe('test');
      })
  }));
});
```

The test always passes event if I change the argument of `subjectService.callNextOnSubject` from `'test'` to anything else.

I have also tried wrapping everything with `async` and `fakeAsync`, but the result is the same.

What would be the correct way to test if `callNextOnSubject` is emitting data to the `serviceSubjectProperty$` Subject?

Comment: You should subscribe *before* calling the method, that subject doesn't have any replay/buffer behaviour.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that worked, thanks.

Comment: When you are unit testing a _service_ you should not be using the angular test infrastructure. All it does is make your test code longer and more error-prone.

Comment: @crdevdeu if one of answers was correct - pls mark it ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found this article while searching for the solution:

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/unit-testing-eventemitter-in-angular-2.0

and it worked well for me (it's very short, don't be afraid to open it).

I'm pasting it here so maybe it will help those which came to this site looking for answer.

---

Regarding the question asked - I think that you need to change:

```
  subjectService.callNextOnSubject('test');

  subjectServiceProperty$.subscribe((message) => {
    expect(message).toBe('test');
  })
```

to

```
  subjectServiceProperty$.subscribe((message) => {
    expect(message).toBe('test');
  })

  subjectService.callNextOnSubject('test');
```

, so subscribe at first, then emit an event.

If you emit `'test'` before subscription, then nothing will "catch" that event.

Answer (score 2):

You should test the data which changed in component after your subject is called. Should testing only public variables, not private or protected;
For example:

service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    onSomeSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject();

    someSubject(string: string) {
        this.onSomeSubject.next(string);
    }
}
```

component:

```
export class SomeComponent {
    @Input() string: string;

    constructor(private service: SomeService) {
        service.onSomeSubject.subscribe((string: string) => {
            this.string = string;
        }); //don't forget to add unsubscribe.
    }
}
```

test:

```
...
describe('SomeService', () => {
    let someService: SomeService; // import SomeService on top
    let someComponent: SomeComponent; // import SomeService on top

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [SomeService, SomeComponent]
        });
        injector = getTestBed();
        someService = injector.get(SomeService);
        someComponent = injector.get(SomeComponent);
    });

    describe('someSubject', () => {
        const string = 'someString';

        it('should change string in component', () => {
            someService.someSubject(string);
            expect(someComponent.string).tobe(string);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jasmine 'done' callback will do the trick so far, check the documentation below:
https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global (see implementationCallback(doneopt))

Below an example using your test case:

```
it('callNextOnSubject() should emit data to serviceSubjectProperty$ Subject', (done) => {
    inject([SubjectService], (subjectService) => {
      subjectService.callNextOnSubject('test');

      subjectServiceProperty$.subscribe((message) => {
        expect(message).toBe('test');
        done();
      })
  }) // function returned by 'inject' has to be invoked
});
```

Comment: Hey @mth khaled, great explanation, however, I get a  TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
  `fit('callNextOn_page() should emit page data', (done) => {
    inject([searchOrderSpy], (_page) => {
      searchOrderSpy._page(5)
    })

    searchOrderSpy._page.subscribe((page) => {
      expect(page).toBe(5);
      done();
    })
  })`and the one below is the implementation in the service `changePage(newPage: number) {
        this._page.next(newPage);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

subscribe must come before, and then call method

```
it(`#${YourCompoent.prototype.yourMethod.name} subscribe must come before, and then call method`, fakeAsync( () => {
    yourServiceSubject.filter$.subscribe(ev => {
      expect(ev).toEqual(mock.mockFilterDefault())
    });
    component.sendFilterForm();
  }));
```